# how to restrict float number to 1 digit after decimal point

Tags: floating-point, decimal, restrict

I have a float number 242.1356783 and -87.10234512,
I need to restrict it it to 242.1
I tried below on cortex m4 microcontroller

1.data[i] = (int)(data[i] *10);
data[i] = data[i]/10;

2.data[i]= ceilf(data[i] * 100)/100;

3.data[i] = roundf(data[i]*100)/100;
but none work.

Anybody has other solution?

Comment: 242.1 is not representable in binary floating point, so all you can hope is to have a close approximation of that. Having the closest approximation is a difficult problem. `roundf(x*10)/10` is not always the closest but not that bad... You should wonder why you want something for which binary float is not appropriate? Is it really what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Floating point (FP) numbers are usually encoded using binary notation: some [whole number * power of 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).

242.1 and -87.1  are then not *exactly* encodable as a FP number.  Instead a nearby one is used.

> I need to restrict it it to 242.1

OP could use the following: (`round()` used instead of `roundf()` to avoid overflow).

```
data[i] = (float) (round(data[i]*10.0)/10);
```

More complex, but does not invoke `double` math, yet handles most cases<sup>*</sup>:

```
// If there is a fraction ...
if (fmodf(data[i], 1.0f) && isfinite(data[i])) {
  data[i] = roundf(data[i]*10.0f)/10;
}
```

---

The **best solution** involves changing the higher level goal.  Perhaps scale the value by 10.  Example: Instead of 242.1 degrees, internally use 2421.0 deci-degrees.

Or wait for language update: C 2x may support decimal FP.

---

Weakness to OP's proposed ideas:

1. `data[i] = (int)(data[i] *10); data[i] = data[i]/10;`: Does not *round* in the right direction in about 50% of the time.   Fails when `data[i] *10` out of `int` range.
2. `data[i]= ceilf(data[i] * 100)/100;`: Does not *round* in the right direction in about 50% of the time.   `data[i] *10` may overflow. I suspect OP wanted 10 here.
3. `data[i] = roundf(data[i]*100)/100;` `data[i] *100` may overflow.  I suspect OP wanted 10 here.

---

<sup>*</sup> May round incorrectly when `data[i]*10.0f` and product is inexact and near xxx.x5